# Grails Security 3.1.2 login of user with role ROLE_ADMIN shows ROLE_NO_ROLES as authorities

Tags: grails, grails-spring-security

I'm testing Grails 3.2.9 with Sec plugin 3.1.2.

Created a user with role ROLE_ADMIN in bootstrap, and added permissions on interceptUrlMap for a test controller "note". After a successful login with that user, I see on the logs my admin has ROLE_NO_ROLES and is denied access to note controller.

> User, role and user role association is on the database.

```
  def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
  def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin').save()
  UserRole.create admin, adminRole
```

> application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.cabolabs.security.User'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.cabolabs.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.cabolabs.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.groupAuthorityNameField = 'authorities'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true

...

grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    [pattern: '/note/**',        access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']],
    [pattern: '/patient/**',     access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']],
    [pattern: '/login/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/logout',         access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/logout/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/dbconsole/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**',             access: ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"]]
]

...
```

> Logs after login, when I try to go to /note/index

```
2017-05-11 23:32:15.793 DEBUG --- [nio-8091-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8d34560b: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: F0902A19E19C23D30B452C332C6C5728; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES
2017-05-11 23:32:15.793 DEBUG --- [nio-8091-exec-4] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_NO_ROLES] one can reach [ROLE_NO_ROLES] in zero or more steps.
2017-05-11 23:32:15.805 DEBUG --- [nio-8091-exec-4] tContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Tried to find pointer on the Sec plugin documentation, but it just mentions ROLE_NO_ROLES once and that is assigned when the user has no roles, that is not this case.

Comment: I have never used role groups, and I may be wrong, but if you say `grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true`, shouldn't you assign your user to a group of roles, instead directly to a role?

Comment: @loteq I didn't find that info on the docs, that if using rolegroups, direct role associations don't work. Also tried to put that setting in false and I had the same behavior. Maybe I just need to delete the project and start again without that option. But still not sure why direct role association to users by UserRole is not working ot get the authorities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have useRoleGroups = true you have to populate your database with :

```
Role adminRole = new Role("ROLE_ADMIN").save()
RoleGroup adminGroup = new RoleGroup("GROUP_ADMIN").save()
RoleGroupRole.create(adminGroup, adminRole, true)
User user = new User("<username>", "<password>").save()
UserRoleGroup.create(user, adminGroup, true)
```

instead of

```
def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin').save()
UserRole.create admin, adminRole
```